# Contact forms on three-dimensional Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, contact-topology

Sorry if this is too simple, but I'm having some trouble working through an exercise given to us by our professor.
The exercise goes as follows:

> For a Lie algebra $\frak{g}$ of dimension three, an element $ \alpha \in \frak g^*$ is called a *contact form* if $\alpha \wedge d\alpha \neq 0 $.
>
> Show that for $\frak g^*$$ = (0,0,12)$, the form $\alpha = e_3$ is a contact form. Determine all the contact forms on this Lie algebra.  Determine which of the other three-dimensional Lie algebras admit a contact form.

I have managed to show that $e_3$ is a contact form for $\frak g^*$$ = (0,0,12)$. I know that we have
$$
de_1=0, \ \ de_2 = 0, \ \ de_3=e_1\wedge e_2
$$
and this gives $e_3 \wedge de_3 = e_3 \wedge e_1 \wedge e_2 \neq 0$, since ${e_1, e_2, e_3}$ are basis elements and thus linearly independent. However, I'm having trouble proceeding further than this and I would appreciate any advice or reference recommendations to solve this.

Comment: Real or complex Lie agebras?

Comment: Are you sure that it says $\mathfrak{g}^*=(0,0,12)$ and not $\mathfrak{g}=(0,0,12)$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde You're right, I tried to shorten the question a bit for brevity but I should have probably left it in it's original form. I will edit my post.